# optimization problem with NDSolve

Tags: programming, numerical-integration, differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize the function `fcc`. When `fcc` is calculated for a specified point the answer is correct:

```
In[70]:= fcc[0.5, 0.5, 0.004, 0.006, 0.0025, 0.5]
Out[70]= 2.96667*10^6
```

but when I want to optimize `fcc` with `NMinimize` there is a problem below:

```
NMinimize[{fcc[q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6], 0.5 <= q1 <= 1.5, 
  0.5 <= q2 <= 1.5, 0.003 <= q3 <= 0.01, 0.003 <= q4 <= 0.01, 
  0.002 <= q5 <= 0.005, 0.5 <= q6 <= 1}, {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable ws. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-((0.00011318 (q2+q3)
>   (-0.0174073+ws[<<1>>]))/(q3 q4
>   q6))+(ws^[Prime])[x]==0,ws[q1]==0.012529},{ws},{x,0,q1}]} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-((0.00011318 (q2+q3)
>   (-0.0174073+ws[<<1>>]))/(q3 q4
>   q6))+(ws^[Prime])[x]==0,ws[q1]==0.012529},{ws},{x,0,q1}]} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing. >>
>
> ReplaceAll::reps: {NDSolve[{-((0.00011318 (q2+q3)
>   (-0.0174073+ws[<<1>>]))/(q3 q4
>   q6))+(ws^[Prime])[x]==0,ws[q1]==0.012529},{ws},{x,0,q1}]} is neither
>   a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot
>   be used for replacing. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed
>   during this calculation. >>
>
> NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable ts. >>
>
> NMinimize::nnum: The function value 2.18625*10^6+6618.38
>   (-0.012529+ws[0]) is not a number at {q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6} =
>   {1.4748,1.12029,0.0074076,0.00951558,0.00291973,0.810076}. >>

and this is the `fcc` function:

```
ta = 30; rha = 0.4; altitude = 1361; p = 
 101325*(1 - altitude*2.25577*10^-5)^5.2559; tka = 
 273.15 + ta; c1 = -5.8002206*10^3; c2 = 1.3914993; c3 = \
-4.8640239*10^-2; c4 = 
 4.1764768*10^-5; c5 = -1.4452093*10^-8; c6 = 6.5459673; psata = 
 Exp[c1/tka + c2 + c3*tka + c4*tka^2 + c5*tka^3 + c6*Log[tka]]; pva = 
 rha*psata; wa = 
 0.621945*pva/(p - 
     pva); tr = 26; rsh = 1500; nu = 7.54; lef = 0.894; tsin = ta; \
tpin = ta; twin = 20; wsin = wa; wpin = wa; tkw = 
 273.17 + twin; psatw = 
 Exp[c1/tkw + c2 + c3*tkw + c4*tkw^2 + c5*tkw^3 + 
   c6*Log[tkw]]; pvw = psatw; wsat = 
 0.621945*pvw/(p - 
     pvw); cps = 1006; cpp = 1006; cpv = 1873; cpw = 4183; ks = \
0.027; kp = 0.027; kwater = 0.6; kwall = 237; hfg = 2501000; lwall = \
0.0005; lwater = 0.001;
fcc[lx_, ly_, lp_, mp_, mw_, ratio_] := Module[{},
   ms = ratio*mp;
   ls = lp;
   dhs = 2*ly*ls/(ly + ls);
   dhp = 2*ly*lp/(ly + lp);
   hs = nu*ks/dhs;
   hp = nu*kp/dhp;
   hm = hs/(lef*cps);
   u = 1/(1/hp + lwall/kwall + lwater/kwater);
   dels = -1; delp = -1;
   wss = NDSolve[{(dels hm ly (ws[x] - wsat))/ms + 
        Derivative[1][ws][x] == 0, ws[lx] == wsin}, {ws}, {x, 0, lx}];
   tstptw = 
    NDSolve[{(dels ly (ts[x] - tw[x]) (hs + 
             cpv hm (-Evaluate[{ws[x]} /. wss] + wsat)))/(ms (cps + 
             cpv Evaluate[{ws[x]} /. wss])) + Derivative[1][ts][x] == 
       0, (delp ly (tp[x] - tw[x]) u)/(mp (cpp + cpv wpin)) + 
        Derivative[1][tp][x] == 0, 
      1/(cpw mw)
          ly (delp (-tp[x] + tw[x]) u + 
           dels (hs (-ts[x] + tw[x]) - 
              hm (hfg + cpv tw[x] - 
                 cpw tw[x]) (Evaluate[{ws[x]} /. wss] - wsat))) + 
        Derivative[1][tw][x] == 0, ts[lx] == tsin, tp[lx] == tpin, 
      tw[0] == twin}, {ts, tp, tw}, {x, 0, lx}];
   (*Plot[Evaluate[{{ts[x],tp[x],tw[x]}/.tstptw}],{x,0,lx}]*)
   tpout = Evaluate[tp[0] /. tstptw]; tpout = tpout[[1]];
   tsout = Evaluate[ts[0] /. tstptw]; tsout = tsout[[1]];
   wsout = Evaluate[ws[0] /. wss]; wsout = wsout[[1]];
   cp = 1006;
   If[(tr - tpout) < 0.5, mt = 20, mt = rsh/(cp*(tr - tpout))];
   np = Round[mt/mp];
   ca = 100;
   at = lx*((np + 1)*(ly + 4*lp) + ly);
   n = 0.6;
   cinv = ca*at^n;
   kel = 120;
   kw = 1.5;
   \[Tau] = 3000;
   \[Eta] = 0.5;
   ro1 = 1.17;
   v1 = ms/(ro1*ls*ly);
   miu1 = 10^-5;
   re1 = ro1*v1*dhs/miu1;
   \[Alpha]1 = ls/ly;
   f1 = 24*(1 - 1.355*\[Alpha]1 + 1.9467*\[Alpha]1^2 - 
        1.7012*\[Alpha]1^3 + 0.9564*\[Alpha]1^4 - 0.2537*\[Alpha]1^5)/
      re1;
   dps = 2*f1*ro1*(v1^2)*lx/dhs;
   smd = 1.17;
   mst = ms*np/smd;
   cos = kel*\[Tau]*((dps*mst)/(\[Eta]*10^6));
   ro2 = 1.17;
   v2 = ms/(ro2*lp*ly);
   miu2 = 10^-5;
   re2 = ro2*v2*dhp/miu2;
   \[Alpha]2 = lp/ly;
   f2 = 24*(1 - 1.355*\[Alpha]2 + 1.9467*\[Alpha]2^2 - 
        1.7012*\[Alpha]2^3 + 0.9564*\[Alpha]2^4 - 0.2537*\[Alpha]2^5)/
      re2;
   dpp = 2*f2*ro2*(v2^2)*lx/dhp;
   pmd = 1.17;
   mpt = mp*np/pmd;
   cop = kel*\[Tau]*((dpp*mpt)/(\[Eta]*10^6));
   h = 2;
   g = 9.81;
   copump = kel*\[Tau]*h*g*mw*np/\[Eta];
   ew = ms*np*(wsout - wsin);
   cow = kw*\[Tau]*3.6*ew;
   r = 0.1;
   y = 10;
   a = r/(1 - (1 + r)^(-y));
   a*cinv + cos + cop + copump + cow];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the previous answer shows while dealing with this type of problem in Mathematica one must use `_?NumericQ` in the function definition. Once you define the function as Mr.Wizard♦ has instructed, it is pretty straightforward to call `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum`. I would also like to scale your function `fcc` by $10^6$. However `FindMinimum` is better suited for this type of multivariate optimization problem where the algorithm can't take advantage of the symbolic processing because the function definition is very **numerical** in nature.

- **FindMinimum**

This is the call to `FindMinimum` with `Sow` and `Reap` to show the convergence for the optimization parameters. I don't have much time so we use `MaxIterations` to be just $40$ but it still took some $106$ sec.

```
resFindMinimum = 
Reap[FindMinimum[{fcc[q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6]/10^6, 
  0.5 <= q1 <= 1.5 && 0.5 <= q2 <= 1.5 && 0.003 <= q3 <= 0.01 && 
   0.003 <= q4 <= 0.01 && 0.002 <= q5 <= 0.005 && 
   0.5 <= q6 <= 1}, {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}, 
 StepMonitor :> Sow[{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}], 
 MaxIterations -> 40]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {106.8161095, Null}

To create the convergence plot to show how the optimization parameters $\{p_1,...,p_6\}$ changes during the optimization function call we use the following

```
col = RandomChoice[ColorData[3, "ColorList"], 6];
GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[
      MapThread[ListLinePlot[#1, Frame -> True, Mesh -> 10, MeshStyle -> Black,   
                PlotStyle -> #2] &,{(resFindMinimum[[2, 1]] // Transpose),col}
         ], 3],
   ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

and finally the result is

```
{10^6 resFindMinimum[[1, 1]], resFindMinimum[[1, 2]]}
```

> {**960785.**, {q1 -> 1.17089, q2 -> 1.17235, q3 -> 0.00969339, q4 -> 0.0096893, q5 -> 0.002, q6 -> 0.748547}}

- **NMinimize**

Similar thing is done by `NMinimize` but this takes more time than it takes in general for `FindMinimum`. However in this case the objective function was further minimized using this algorithm costing $217$ sec of my CPU. I limited the `MaxIterations` to force the algorithm to stop.

```
resNMinimize = 
Reap[NMinimize[{fcc[q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6]/10^6, 
  0.5 <= q1 <= 1.5 && 0.5 <= q2 <= 1.5 && 0.003 <= q3 <= 0.01 && 
   0.003 <= q4 <= 0.01 && 0.002 <= q5 <= 0.005 && 
   0.5 <= q6 <= 1}, {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}, 
 StepMonitor :> Sow[{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}], 
 MaxIterations -> 40]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {217.2744274, Null}

[image]

The result is better

> {**734721.**, {q1 -> 0.82917, q2 -> 1.21265, q3 -> 0.00332494,q4 -> 0.00986184, q5 -> 0.002, q6 -> 0.999981}}

- **Can we make FindMinimum better?**

One often needs to give a better initial guess to `FindMinimum` to resolve a optimization problem that has stalled at some local minimum. We can use the `NMinimize` result to provide `FindMinimum` a better starting point. The new guesses are

```
{{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6},{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}/.resNMinimize[[1, 2]]}//Transpose
```

> {{q1, 0.82917}, {q2, 1.21265}, {q3, 0.00332494}, {q4,0.00986184}, {q5, 0.002}, {q6, 0.999981}}

Again I run `FindMinimum` just for $40$ iterations.

```
NresFindMinimum = 
Reap[FindMinimum[{fcc[q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6]/10^6, 
  0.5 <= q1 <= 1.5 && 0.5 <= q2 <= 1.5 && 0.003 <= q3 <= 0.01 && 
   0.003 <= q4 <= 0.01 && 0.002 <= q5 <= 0.005 && 
   0.5 <= q6 <= 1}, {{q1, 0.829170177410782`}, {q2, 
   1.212649238425597`}, {q3, 0.003324936752031159`}, {q4, 
   0.00986184329841919`}, {q5, 0.0020000030660318143`}, {q6, 
   0.9999807985249598`}}, 
 StepMonitor :> Sow[{q1, q2, q3, q4, q5, q6}], 
 MaxIterations -> 40]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {159.2921110, Null}

However we don't get any better result though it took $159$ sec.

`{10^6 NresFindMinimum[[1, 1]], NresFindMinimum[[1, 2]]}`

> {**819476.**, {q1 -> 0.796225, q2 -> 1.14357, q3 -> 0.00400138,q4 -> 0.00916374, q5 -> 0.002, q6 -> 0.998775}}

The convergence graph seems to tell my current lack of time is a problem for `FindMinimum`!!! Please check the Mathematica constraint optimization [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).
[image]

Comment: @dear PlatoManiac lots of thanks for your attention and answer

Answer (score 5):

For a start you need `_?NumericQ` (search the site for `NumericQ` for many other examples) and you need to localize your variable in `Module`.  `fcc` should be defined:

```
fcc[
  lx_?NumericQ,
  ly_?NumericQ,
  lp_?NumericQ,
  mp_?NumericQ, 
  mw_?NumericQ,
  ratio_?NumericQ
] :=
  Module[{ms, ls, dhs, dhp, hs, hp, hm, u, dels, delp, wss, ws, tstptw,
    ts, tw, tp, tpout, tsout, wsout, cp, mt, np, ca, at, n, cinv, kel,
    kw, \[Tau], \[Eta], ro1, v1, miu1, re1, \[Alpha]1, f1, dps, smd, 
    mst, cos, ro2, v2, miu2, re2, \[Alpha]2, f2, dpp, pmd, mpt, cop, h,
    g, copump, ew, cow, r, y, a}, 

   (* the rest of your code *)

  ]
```

With this I still get errors:

> NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors
>   {-4.09654*10^-7,-1.40957*10^-7,0.} in the boundary value residuals.
>   Returning the best solution found. >>
>
> NDSolve::bvluc: The equations derived from the boundary conditions are
>   numerically ill-conditioned. The boundary conditions may not be
>   sufficient to uniquely define a solution. The computed solution may
>   match the boundary conditions poorly. >>
>
> NDSolve::berr: There are significant errors {1.01351,0.148459,0.} in
>   the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>

however I don't feel like working these out for you.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer

Comment: @xazar You're welcome.  Sorry I don't have a complete answer without errors for you, but that's a lot of math to work through!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks for the reopen. Ah, well yes, the question could be shorter, but at least it had all information/code to run the problem. I deleted my comments.

Comment: @ruebenko I reopened this question at your request; I'm curious, are you intending to post an answer?