# FindMaximum with parametrized NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a parametrized ODE, and wanting to find the parameter that maximize the solution at a specific point.

For example, in the following code I am trying to solve the ODE $df/dz=t \cos(f)$ that is parametrized by $t$ and find the parameter $t$ that maximized the solution at $z=5$:

```
sol[t_?NumericQ] := 
 First@NDSolve[{f'[z] == t Cos[f[z]], f[0] == 1}, {f}, {z, 0, 10}]
FindMaximum[f[5] /. sol[t], {t, 1}]
```

Execution of the code finds an answer, but with a bunch of error messages like

```
ReplaceAll: {sol[t]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing
```

Note that I have specified that the parameter `t` is a numerical value by `t_?NumericQ` above.  This has been suggested as the solution to similar problems in this forum, e.g. in [optimization problem with NDSolve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6751/optimization-problem-with-ndsolve), but it doesn't solve my issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue.html) as follows:

```
pfunc = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[z] == t Cos[f[z]], f[0] == 1}, f, {z, 0, 10}, {t}];

FindMaximum[pfunc[t][5], {t, 1}]
```

> {1.5708, {t -> 21.}}

**Update:** *"is there a way to use NDSolve?"*

```
ClearAll[sol, func]
sol[t_?NumericQ] := First @ NDSolve[{f'[z] == t  Cos[f[z]], f[0] == 1}, f, {z, 0, 10}]
func[t_?NumericQ] := f[5] /. sol[t];
FindMaximum[func[t], {t, 1}]
```

> {1.5708, {t -> 21.}}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is there a way to use `NDSolve`?  The actual problem is more complicated, and it will be the best to use `NDSolve` in that situation....

Comment: @dashmile, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks!  So in the end using `NumericQ` was the key again.